# How to update membership object from product after insert?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk-api

I am using the bulk api to upload a CSV file to a custom object with the same fields as my CSV file. I then use an 'after insert' trigger to insert the data from the CSV custom object into the proper objects. I have a field called MemberType__c in the CSV custom object that is essentially the Product.

My question is, how do I update my Custom Membership Object with the Product Id when it matches the MemberType__c field?

The values are already int he products table.. for example "Gold," "Commercial," ect.

So basically, if MemberType__c = Products.Name update Products lookup relationship in Membership__c object.

Here is my trigger.

```
trigger OnUploadInsert on CSVUpload__c (after insert) {
    Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[] {};
    Boat__c[] boats = new Boat__c[] {};
    Membership__c[] memberships = new Membership__c[]{};
    Order[] orders = new Order[]{};
    Promotion_Code__c[] promos = new Promotion_Code__c[]{};

    for (CSVUpload__c u : Trigger.new) {
        accounts.add(new Account(
                Name = u.FirstName__c + ' ' + u.LastName__c
        ));
        contacts.add(new Contact(
                FirstName = u.FirstName__c,
                LastName = u.LastName__c,
                MailingStreet = u.Address__c,
                MailingCity = u.City__c,
                MailingStateCode = u.State__c,
                MailingPostalCode = u.Zip__c,
                HomePhone = u.HomePhone__c,
                OtherPhone = u.BusinessPhone__c,
                MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone__c,
                Email = u.EmailAddress__C,
                Title = u.Title__c,
                Fax = u.FaxNo__c
        ));
        boats.add(new Boat__c(
               Address__c = u.BoatAddress__c,
               City__c = u.BoatCity__c,
               State__c = u.BoatState__c,
               Zip__c = u.BoatZip__c,
               Country__c = u.BoatCountry__c
        ));
        memberships.add(new Membership__c(
               Auto_Renew__c = u.AutoReNew__c,
               MemberSince__c = u.MemberSince__c,
               Expiration__c = u.ExpireDate__c,
               MemberSource__c = u.MemberSource__c,
               MemberStatus__c = u.MemberStatus__c,
               Trailer_Care__c = u.TrailerCoverage__c
        ));
        orders.add(new Order(
               Status = 'Draft',
               TypeAmt__c = u.TypeAmt__c,
               PoDate = u.TransDate__c,
               EffectiveDate = u.EffectiveDate__c
        ));
        promos.add(new Promotion_Code__c(
               Code__c = u.PromCode__c
        ));
    }
    insert accounts;
    for (Integer i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        contacts[i].AccountId = accounts[i].Id;
        boats[i].Account__c = accounts[i].Id;
        memberships[i].Account__c = accounts[i].Id;
        orders[i].AccountId = accounts[i].Id;
    }

    insert contacts;
    insert boats;
    insert memberships;

    for(Integer m = 0; m < memberships.size(); m++)
    {
        orders[m].Membership__c = memberships[m].Id;
    }

    insert orders;

    for(Integer o = 0; o < orders.size(); o++)
    {
        promos[o].Order__c = orders[o].Id;
    }

    insert promos;
}
```

I'm sorry if this seems trivial as I am new to APEX/Salesforce/Bulk API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be needing to use Sets and Maps to query Product having name as MemberType field in CSV object and update the Membership Object with the Product Id.

```
trigger OnUploadInsert on CSVUpload__c (after insert) {
    Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[] {};
    Boat__c[] boats = new Boat__c[] {};
    Membership__c[] memberships = new Membership__c[]{};
    Order[] orders = new Order[]{};
    Promotion_Code__c[] promos = new Promotion_Code__c[]{};
    // Start - Added for Product mapping
    Set<String> setMemberType = new Set<String>(); // Used to store MemberType from CSVUpload__c object
    Map<String,Id> mapMemberTypeProductId = new Map<String,Id>(); // Used to store map of MemberType to Product Id
    // End - Added for Product mapping
    for (CSVUpload__c u : Trigger.new) {
        accounts.add(new Account(
                Name = u.FirstName__c + ' ' + u.LastName__c
        ));
        contacts.add(new Contact(
                FirstName = u.FirstName__c,
                LastName = u.LastName__c,
                MailingStreet = u.Address__c,
                MailingCity = u.City__c,
                MailingStateCode = u.State__c,
                MailingPostalCode = u.Zip__c,
                HomePhone = u.HomePhone__c,
                OtherPhone = u.BusinessPhone__c,
                MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone__c,
                Email = u.EmailAddress__C,
                Title = u.Title__c,
                Fax = u.FaxNo__c
        ));
        boats.add(new Boat__c(
               Address__c = u.BoatAddress__c,
               City__c = u.BoatCity__c,
               State__c = u.BoatState__c,
               Zip__c = u.BoatZip__c,
               Country__c = u.BoatCountry__c
        ));
        memberships.add(new Membership__c(
               Auto_Renew__c = u.AutoReNew__c,
               MemberSince__c = u.MemberSince__c,
               Expiration__c = u.ExpireDate__c,
               MemberSource__c = u.MemberSource__c,
               MemberStatus__c = u.MemberStatus__c,
               Trailer_Care__c = u.TrailerCoverage__c
        ));
        orders.add(new Order(
               Status = 'Draft',
               TypeAmt__c = u.TypeAmt__c,
               PoDate = u.TransDate__c,
               EffectiveDate = u.EffectiveDate__c
        ));
        promos.add(new Promotion_Code__c(
               Code__c = u.PromCode__c
        ));
        // Start - Added for Product Mapping
        setMemberType.add(u.MemberType__c );
        // End - Added for Product Mapping
    }
    insert accounts;
    for (Integer i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        contacts[i].AccountId = accounts[i].Id;
        boats[i].Account__c = accounts[i].Id;
        memberships[i].Account__c = accounts[i].Id;
        orders[i].AccountId = accounts[i].Id;
    }

    insert contacts;
    insert boats;
    insert memberships;

    for(Integer m = 0; m < memberships.size(); m++)
    {
        orders[m].Membership__c = memberships[m].Id;
    }

    insert orders;

    for(Integer o = 0; o < orders.size(); o++)
    {
        promos[o].Order__c = orders[o].Id;
    }

    insert promos;

    // Start - Added for Product Mapping
    // Iterate over Product object and populate map with Product Name and Product Id
    for(Product2 p : [Select Id,Name From Product2 Where Name IN : setMemberType]) {
        mapMemberTypeProductId.put(p.Name,p.Id);
    }
    // Iterate over memberships and populate Product__c field from the map
    for(Integer j = 0; j < memberships.size(); j++)
    {
        memberships[j].Product__c = mapMemberTypeProductId.get(Trigger.new[j].MemberType__c);
    }

    update memberships;
    // End - Added for Product Mapping
}
```

I have modified the trigger you wrote. I added comments which should be self explanatory. The modified code will be within // Start and // End comments.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dude, awesome solution! I had to fix a few things, which wasn't a big deal. When setting it, u. was missing.. so changed to from setMemberType.add(MemberType__c); to setMemberType.add(u.MemberType__c).. also changed memberships[m].Product__c to memberships[j].Product__c... but other than that.. it was perfect.. especially without testing it! Thanks again!

Comment: Updated it. Sorry for that. Glad it helped you.